# WPF-Application icon is only changing properly after pinning and unpinning it to the Windows-taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, icons, taskbar

So I wrote an WPF application, which shows different project status from a buildserver.
The status given from the server, are beneficial for the MainIcon of the application.

I added the 4 icons (red, orange, yellow, green) as resources and used them with an IMultiValueConverter which determines what icon should be set/used.

The problem is, that when the TaskbarIcon changes while debugging, everything works as intended and the icon is changing properly.
But when I publish the application, the icon switches to the default icon and will only change to the right icon if I pin and unpin it from the TaskBar. Afterwards the changing works fine all the time, it's only at the start of the program that I need to pin and unpin it.
I've read, that it may be a Windows based problem/bug, but I'm not sure about that.
Is there any way to solve this problem? Any workaround?

*Edit

```cs
// This is a snippet from the converter class where the icon gets selected

public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
          MainMonitorWindowViewModel mainViewModel =
                (MainMonitorWindowViewModel)((MainMonitorWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)?.DataContext;
            if (values is ObservableCollection<BuildServerProjekt> col)
            {
                int amountYellow = 0;
                int amountOrange = 0;

                //this is to determine whether yellow or orange dominates in the list
                foreach (BuildServerProjekt buildServerProjekt in col)
                {
                    switch (buildServerProjekt.Activity)
                    {
                        case "Wird gebaut" when buildServerProjekt.BuildStatus == "Failure":
                            amountOrange++;
                            break;
                        case "Wird gebaut":
                            amountYellow++;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                bool isBuilding = col.Any(x => x.Activity == "Wird gebaut");
                bool isBroken = col.Any(x =>
                    (x.Status == "Fehlgeschlagen" || x.Status == "Ausnahme wurde ausgelöst") && x.Activity != "Wird gebaut");
                bool isOK = col.Any(x => x.Status == "Erfolgreich");

                if (isBroken)
                {
                    if (mainViewModel == null)
                    {
                        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SPBSMonitor;Component/icons/red256.ico"));
                    }
                    // here I set the MainIcon (TaskBar icon)
                    mainViewModel.MainIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SPBSMonitor;Component/icons/red256.ico"));
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SPBSMonitor;Component/icons/red256.ico"));

                }
[...]
```

The binding in the xaml code (the return from the converter) is for the NotifyIcon Assembly http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon which is only important for the TrayIcon (which works perfectly fine updating).

`mainViewModel.MainIcon` is a property in my ViewModel (MVVM) which is binded to Window.Icon :

```
<Window x:Class="SP.BSMonitor.View.MainMonitorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SP.BSMonitor"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
        xmlns:mvConverter="clr-namespace:SP.BSMonitor.MVConverter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        MouseDown="MainMonitorWindow_OnMouseDown"
        Title="Build-Monitor" MinHeight="380" MinWidth="800" Height="380" Width="800"
        Loaded="MainMonitorWindow_OnLoaded" Closing="MainMonitorWindow_OnClosing" Name="Hauptfenster" ShowInTaskbar="True" Icon="{Binding MainIcon}">
```

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: The code may not be helpful, that's why I didn't consider posting it, because it is working as intended. But I will add code, which could be helpful to elaborate my problem further.

Comment: Are you deploying your app via ClickOnce? This question ran into the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389433/wpf-app-doesnt-update-taskbar-icon - it may be due to where ClickOnce is deploying your app.